# getting file from date range of the current directory

Tags: python

This is my example path: 'c:\Data\2015-08-01'

Currently I'm getting all the files inside on one(1) specific date, but my goal is to get the files with date range of file folder. Example is to get 2015-08-01 to 2015-08-05' just like the `BETWEEN` query in MySQL

```
import os
import os.path
import tempfile

dateStart = '2015-08-01'
dateEnd = '2015-08-05'

year = dateStart[0:4]
yearMonth = year + '_' + dateStart[5:7] 

pathDir = 'c:\\Data'
date_folder = pathDir  + '\\' + dateStart

count = 0
for filefolder in os.listdir(date_folder):
     filefolder = date_folder + "\\" + filefolder
        for file in os.listdir(filefolder): 
            if "txt" in file:
                filename = filefolder + "\\" + file 
                    print filename
                    #Output of this, is all text files for this date only '2015-08-01'
```

Its hard for me to loop to pull files for date range e.g. '2015-08-01' to '2015-08-05'. How to do this?

Note that there is a folder after my dates and the textfiles are in the last. and the textfile containing on that folder is my point to get. so that from my old code I used this: filefolder = date_folder + "\" + filefolder to get the text in 1 date only.

Here is my sample real path data:

```
 \\10.81.67.162\DLCx Logs\DLCx02\2015\2015_08\2015-08-01\Folder\data.text
```

and if I will get the range from 2015-08-01 to 2015-08-01. this will be the output:

```
 \\10.81.67.162\DLCx Logs\DLCx02\2015\2015_08\2015-08-01\Folder\data.text
 \\10.81.67.162\DLCx Logs\DLCx02\2015\2015_08\2015-08-02\Folder\data.text
 \\10.81.67.162\DLCx Logs\DLCx02\2015\2015_08\2015-08-03\Folder\data.text
 \\10.81.67.162\DLCx Logs\DLCx02\2015\2015_08\2015-08-04\Folder\data.text
 \\10.81.67.162\DLCx Logs\DLCx02\2015\2015_08\2015-08-05\Folder\data.text
```

Comment: You said txt in the code then showed text in the example. Which one is true? Also, have you tried my solution? It does look for one folder level below the date folder.

Comment: Both of your solution is true but I cannot show the txt files weird. im using the suggested code of Martineau. Its almost done I cannot go through the textfiles because there is one folder before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module makes doing date arithmetic, comparisons, as well as converting them to or from strings relatively easy.

Here's how it could be used to do what you're trying to accomplish (at least according to your most recent comments):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from glob import glob
from os import path

DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'
SUBFOLDER_PATH_FORMAT = r'%Y\%Y_%m\%Y-%m-%d\Folder'
pathDir = r'\\10.81.67.162\DLCx Logs\DLCx02'
dateStart = '2015-08-01'
dateEnd = '2015-09-01'
start_date = datetime.strptime(dateStart, DATE_FORMAT).date()
end_date = datetime.strptime(dateEnd, DATE_FORMAT).date()
delta_one_day = timedelta(days=1)

date = start_date
while date <= end_date:
    subfolder_path = date.strftime(SUBFOLDER_PATH_FORMAT)
    data_folder = path.join(pathDir, subfolder_path)
    if path.isdir(data_folder):
        for filename in glob(os.path.join(data_folder, '*.txt')):
            print filename
    date += delta_one_day
```

Comment: Didn't see you answer until just now. But I've given (exactly) the same answer :-) Didn't know about DATE_FORMAT though - need to remember that one.

Comment: @NZD: Actually our answers differ quite a bit in how they accomplish things. Anyway, `DATE_FORMAT` is just a hardcoded [formatting string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for use with `strptime()` (and `strftime()`).

Comment: 1. The basic idea is the same - we both use the date strings converted to date objects and that allows us to specify a range that can be compared against. It is mainly the order in which we do things that differs. 2. I should have realised that it should be possible to pass a format string to the datetime routine instead of trying to parse the date string myself. This is Python after all.

Comment: @NZD: Well they accomplish many of the same things, but in largely different ways. Since it's Python, one is better off learning and making use of the built-ins as much as possible. It not only does it require less coding and debugging, the result often runs faster than re-inventing the wheel and doing things yourself.

Comment: I tried your suggested code but it doesn't print the filename I just paste my real path  - > \\10.11.12.13\Logs\

Comment: It should be fairly obvious how to modify my answer so it handles what you're now saying you really want. Here's a hint to get started: `pathdir = '\\\\10.81.67.162\\DLCx Logs\\DLCx02\\2015\\2015_08'`.

Comment: I know this is closed but my concern is, when I get the file from the same month range e.g. 2015-08-01 to 2015-08-31 it is working, but if I will set the different month range 2015-08-01 to 2015-09-01 it will be failed because the file arrangement is 2015_07, 2015_08, 2015_09. Could you suggest me again for this problem?

Comment: I think that is not the exact solution, I mean the file format is: 2015_07/2015-07-01/file.txt,    2015_08/2015-08-01/file.txt,      2015_09/2015-09-01/file.txt.... Something like that so that loop cannot be jump for the next month of the file path.

Comment: It should be clear by now how to adjust the code further yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my approach: start with separate year, month, day and build the date:

```
import glob
import os


pattern = os.path.join(r'C:\Data', '{}-{:02}-{:02}', '*', '*.txt')

year, month = 2015, 8
start_day, end_day = 1, 5

for day in range(start_day, end_day + 1):
    wildcard = pattern.format(year, month, day)
    for filename in glob.glob(wildcard):
        print filename
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easiest to convert your dates to date objects. You can then just compare them. See example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import os.path
import tempfile
import datetime
import re

dateStart = '2015-08-03'
dateEnd = '2015-08-05'

# helper function to convert date strings to date objects
def make_dt(ds):
    return datetime.date(int(ds[0:4]), int(ds[5:7]), int(ds[8:10]))

# convert date string to date object
dt_start = make_dt(dateStart)
dt_end = make_dt(dateEnd)

pathDir = '.'

if __name__ == "__main__":

    for folder in os.listdir(pathDir):
        # only folders that match date format yyyy-mm-dd
        if re.match("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}", folder):
            # convert folder name to date object
            dt_folder = make_dt(folder)
            if (dt_folder <= dt_end) and (dt_folder >= dt_start):
                print "folder %s is between start [%s] and end [%s]" % (folder, dateStart, dateEnd)
```